# Javascript Errors when changing paragraphs

Tags: javascript

So I'm trying to make a page display different paragraphs for each button pressed. However I keep getting some errors where the button will not run the function correctly.
Ex

```js
function examplefunction() {
  document.getElemtentById("paragraphtobechanged").innerHTML = "When I put more "" it fails in other words it will not write this part."
  }
```

```html
<button onclick="examplefunction()">Change Paragraph</button>
<p id="paragraphtobechanged"></p>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It should be:

```
function examplefunction() {
  document.getElemtentById("paragraphtobechanged").innerHTML = "When I put more \"\" it fails in other words it will not write this part."
  }
```

You need to escape the double quotation marks. Or you can do:

```
function examplefunction() {
      document.getElemtentById("paragraphtobechanged").innerHTML = 'When I put more "" it fails in other words it will not write this part.'
      }
```

Answer (score 1):

@TheDude was on the right track, but there's something else. You spelt element wrong in your example:

```
function examplefunction() {
                V
  document.getElementById("paragraphtobechanged").innerHTML = "When I put more \"\" it fails in other words it will not write this part."
  }
```

Answer (score 0):

The issue here is with the actual string.

```
// Option 1
"When I put more \"\" it fails in other words it will not write this part."


// Option 2
'When I put more "" it fails in other words it will not write this part.'
```

Note: Option 2 works with your case but if you're using **both** single-quotes and double-quotes within your actual string you'll have to escape one or the other.